# SSL with certificates working in Java but not in C#

Tags: c#, java, ssl, certificate

I have to call a service that requires SSL with client authentication.
I have a p12 client certificate (private and public) and a public remote server certificate.

Java client:
The remote certificate is in a jks and the service works fine.

c#:
I try to authenticate with the same p12 and loaded the pem (exported from the jks with keytool) into LocalComputer Personal folder, but I got an exception:

```
 The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

I examined the details of the server certificate and found that the chain cannot be completed; I thought because the scope of the issuer of the certificate does not contain the Signatures right.

If this is correct, why java is working?
If this is not correct why C# is not working?
How can I force C# to treat the certificate from the server as valid?
In Windows must I always pass through the Certificates snap-in and LocalComputer and so on or I can embed the trust in my client application?

**Update:**

I have changed the the title and removed the *web-services* tag because it's not a web-service specific  issue, but SSL instead; so:
**Title was**: WS call with client certificate working in Java but not in C#
**Title is now**: SSL with certificates working in Java but not in C#

Now I've got my C# system working through a call to a java application, but I don't like it very much.
I tested the application using the same certificate set on the same system on various environments and stated that the violation of the trust chain doesn't allow my c# client to connect through SSL, but java ignores it.

So my final question is: does java ignore the completeness of the entire trust chain when setting up a SSL connection?

Comment: I think that trusted certificates in java and C# differs. Java uses its own certificate storages, which can have needed certificate. And C# can miss it.

Comment: Unless the Java code itself has disabled trust management (which it shouldn't do), Java should verify the remote certificate in the same way as C#. Note that the JRE uses its own trust store, which may be different from the Windows store used by C#. You could verify that the server is well configured too. In addition, Java 7 may also be using SNI, when your C# client might not (in which case it would return a different certificate): you can check this by looking at the handshake with Wireshark, for example.

Answer (score -1):

There usually occurs because either of the following are true:

- The certificate is self-signed and not added as a trusted certificate.
- The certificate is expired.
- The certificate is signed by a root certificate that's not installed on your machine.
- A revocation list is probed, but cannot be found/used.

Try getting some information about the certificate of the server and see if you need to install any specific certs on your client to get it to work.

Comment: The certificate is signed by a root certificate but this root certificate is not a CA. How can I tell C# to accept it anyway? Why java can avoid this check?